# How can I control the main vertical and horizontal spaces of pages?

Tags: spacing

I printed my report, but I saw that it has the same big space around the content for every page. How can I change it?

Comment: Welcome you want to change the margins? Package `gemoetry`. Do you want to change the paper size? Still package `geometry` :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in comments section.

Comment: beware if you are printing on standard A4 or US letter paper and make the margins small the text lines will be too long to read unless you use (at least) two columns. there is a reason that the default text width is not wider.